# Finding and removing address duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find and mark duplicates in millions of addresses, but a complex statement is taking too much time. I am wondering if there is a simple way of doing this? I have an index on the address, city, state, zip fields. I want to be able to identify the duplicates by marking a status field with "D" for example. Is there a simple way of doing this, using simple SQL code?

Comment: You need to provide more information for anyone to be able to help. Sample data, table structure, definition of duplicate etc

Comment: And show us your "complex" statement? Trying to detect duplicates from millions of rows is very likely to take a long time.

Comment: It should not take a long time since the rows are indexed, by zip, state, city, address (in this order). In fact if I was to use a 3rd gen language I would just loop on the rows and compare the current row's fields to the previous row's fields and then if they are the same mark the status field. But as I am new to SQL Server and do not know if there is a way of looping using a program like with php-mysql, I am struck trying to figure out these complex structures as in the first answer.

Comment: Just because a table is indexed doesn't mean it magically runs at the speed of light - it depends how much work it has to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CTE` to identify duplicate addresses.

Note the `order by (select null)`  ... you can specify a more appropriate order if desired.

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
        , RN = row_number() over (partition by address, city, state, zip order by (select null))
    From YourTable
)
Update cte set Status_Field='D'
Where RN > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I am new to SQL Server, I am having a hard time grasping the logic of how it is written. Is there a way to do programs like when using php with mysql? Can you point me to an example? Thanks

Comment: @jack_humphrey No need for php, it would be far more efficient in SQL Server.  Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=244bb0a55c11b2bc6003b7fe4c033597

Comment: I went to the link. I will try it on my table and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: That worked very well. You solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @jack_humphrey Always happy to help.  If you found it helpful, feel free to ACCEPT the answer.